# Get Text from Multiple EditText with Button in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

My problem is creating activity to enter an array manually in Android. So I tried to create multiple EditText by these code lines:

```
public void EnterArray(int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);
            EditText txt = new EditText(this);
            txt.setId(i);           
            layout.addView(txt, params);
    }
}
```

The remain problem is how can I get the text from them by using the Save Button I create in the layout. Is there any resolve? I hope there's someone could help with it.

Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
int count =layout.getChildCount();

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
EditText text=(EditText)layout.getChildAt(i);
String value= text.getText().toString()

}
```